# How can I download Rust API docs?

Tags: rust

Is there a way I can download the API library docs for Rust or generate them? The only docs I can find in the Rust source are in [`src/docs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/doc).

I'm running the nightly build, so I'm sure there's a way to generate all the docs in the same fashion as the [standard docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) using `rustdoc`, I just can't find it!

I'm running Linux, with the nightly build, using this command:

```
curl -s https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Rustup**

If you use [rustup](https://rustup.rs/), the [recommended way to install and update Rust](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/12/22/Rust-1.14.html), then the docs may already be installed; the default installation behavior has changed over time. Try running `rustup doc` to open them in your browser.

If they aren't already installed, you can download the docs by running `rustup component add rust-docs`.

By default, `rustup doc` opens the documentation front page, but you can add `--std` to jump straight to the standard API docs or `--book` for *The Rust Programming Language*. You can also use `rustup doc std::iter::Iterator` to open the documentation of a specific item.

[rustup 1.20](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/10/15/Rustup-1.20.0.html) learned the concept of *profiles*. These allow you to default to having docs installed for a toolchain (via the `default` profile) or not (via the `minimal` profile).

**Standalone Rust Installer**

The Rust installer also installs the documentation for the language and for Cargo. On Linux systems, it can be found at `/usr/local/share/doc/{rust,cargo}`.

Comment: Please note, the above does at the moment not work for M1 macs. https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2692

Comment: @Shepmaster This opens the documentation in a browser. Is there a way to open and navigate within the terminal (say in a remote server situation)?

Comment: @analytical_prat to my knowledge, Rust does not produce non-HTML forms of the documentation. I'd suggest looking at using a CLI browser (e.g. [lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/)) or one of the other tools listed below that re-format the Rust documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to have the Rust docs (and a few others from languages to frameworks to CLI tools) for offline use is to install [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/) for Linux or [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) for OS X and download Rust's documentation from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running Arch, install [`rust-docs`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/rust-docs/) and navigate to `file:///usr/share/doc/rust/html/index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding a link to file:///usr/local/share/doc/rust/html/index.html in your browser/desktops bookmarks.

Comment: This won't work for most people, who install Rust using the recommended method of rustup.