# How do I view rustdoc for a library my project depends on?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I'd like to view the rust docs for a library that my program depends on. How can I pull these down? I found a question with the answer for the [standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592046/how-can-i-download-rust-api-docs) but I'm looking specifically for crates.io dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cargo does that automatically. For example, if I have hyper as a dependency, `cargo doc` produces docs for it starting at `target/doc/hyper/index.html`.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to check there! Thank you

Comment: I think `cargo doc --open` should open the doc of current project (along side with all dependencies crate)