# How to read bytes from a Windows file handle in Rust?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I am implementing a DLL using Rust. The DLL's host application passes Win32 file handles to the DLL for reading and writing.

Is there some function existing that returns a "normal" Rust reader from a Windows file handle? How would a manual implementation of the `Read` or `Write` trait look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, there is a platform-specific trait [`FromRawHandle`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/ext/io.rs#L38-L52), which is implemented for `std::fs::File` and `std::process::Stdio`.

Using this *transfers ownership of the handle*; when the `File` or `Stdio` is dropped, the handle will be closed. Make sure that matches with your API and use it accordingly.

---

There is an equivalent trait for *nix platforms: [`FromRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It would be great if `std::os::windows` docs would be part of the public documentation at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/index.html .

Comment: @blerontin [yep](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24658), people have been wanting that [for a while](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1998). Perhaps that would be a good contribution that you can make to Rust! In the meantime, you probably [already have the Windows-specific docs installed locally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27592046/155423), so `rustup doc` will show them to you.