# mdbook 0.1.7 install fails with errors when compiling the backtrace crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to read *The Rust Programming Language*. I have cloned the repository from GitHub and it says to install `mdbook` by `cargo install mdbook --vers 0.1.7`. When I do this, I get error messages from compiling `backtrace`. What am I doing wrong?

The first error message is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types    --> /home/martin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.12/src/symbolize/libbacktrace.rs:156:60
    | 
156 |         STATE = bt::backtrace_create_state(ptr::null(), 0, error_cb,
    |                                                            ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::os::raw::c_void`, found enum `libc::c_void`
    |
    = note: expected type `extern "C" fn(*mut std::os::raw::c_void, *const i8, i32)`
               found type `extern "C" fn(*mut libc::c_void, *const i8, i32) {symbolize::libbacktrace::error_cb}`
```

Comment: *I am trying to read* — it's [available online](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and [installed locally when you install Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27592046/155423); you don't need to build it yourself.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your error messages by copying them directly from your terminal and pasting them as code. The error markers (`^^^^`) are misaligned, a telltale sign that something has gone awry.

Comment: Which version of Rust do you have? Backtrace has [issues with Rust < 1.30](https://github.com/alexcrichton/backtrace-rs/issues/141)